# Golang function not reading the file names correctly

Tags: csv, go, file-handling

So, I've got a repository which has several .csv files, they contain the table schema for a database. I have written a Golang code that gets the list of the file names from the repo, then opens these files, reads the content and creates a MySQL CREATE query.

The issue that I'm facing is that for certain .csv files, the Golang code ends up reading the title wrong, which is causing problems in the later stages. Like for instance, there are files with the names -- config_hr.csv, config_oe.csv, contribution_analysis.csv which is being read as onfig_hr.csv, onfig_oe.csv, ontribution_analysi.csv. This issue seems to be addressed if I were to capitalize the names, but that has many other problems in the later stages of our project.

Is this some kind of an encoding issue? I have checked the code on Windows, Mac and Linux, with Golang version being the latest v1.21, any help or insight would be highly appreciated!

Snippet of the Golang code reading the names of the CSV files

```
entries, err := FileEntry.Readdir(0)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Now, open all the files one by one, and extract the content of the files.
    // Then modify the resultant string to be of MySQL compatibility.
    for _, e := range entries {
        // Mimicking the SQL Query of Table Creation query.
        Query_String := ("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + strings.ToLower(strings.Trim(strings.Replace(e.Name(), " ", "_", -1), ".csv")) + " (\n")
        fmt.Println("Opening -- " + file_folder + "/" + e.Name())
        file, err := os.Open(file_folder + "/" + e.Name())
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer file.Close()
        // Reading the CSV file from path.
        reader := csv.NewReader(file)
        records, err := reader.ReadAll()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
```

Comment: A [mre] would show you exactly where you have a problem: https://go.dev/play/p/gsDTH8eRHI8. You are incorrectly using [`strings.Trim`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Trim) _"Trim returns a slice of the string s with all leading and trailing Unicode code points contained in cutset removed"_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `string.Trim` funtion with below function.

```golang
// getFileNameWithoutExtension takes a file path as input and returns
// the file name without its extension. It utilizes the filepath package
// to extract the base name and then removes the extension.
func getFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath string) string {
    // Get the base name of the file path (including extension)
    baseName := filepath.Base(filePath)

    // Calculate the length to remove the extension from the base name
    // and obtain the file name without extension
    fileNameWithoutExtension := baseName[:len(baseName)-len(filepath.Ext(baseName))]

    // Return the file name without extension
    return fileNameWithoutExtension
}
```

Sample code:

```golang
 Query_String := ("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + strings.ToLower(getFileNameWithoutExtension(strings.Replace(e.Name(), " ", "_", -1))) + " (\n")
```

Comment: Or just `return filePath[:len(filePath)-4]` because OP only wants these for files ending with `".csv"`.

Comment: You can modify it, but `getFileNameWithoutExtension` is a generic function. You can reuse it for other files in the future. Improving reusability is a good practice in programming.

Answer (score 3):

It's not an encoding issue, it's a `strings.Trim` issue. `strings.Trim` will trim from the beginning and end using a cutset, not a string. So your ".csv" is saying essentially "if stuff in this set is at the beginning or end of the string, cut it. You'd experience the same issue if your file was named `svconfig_oe.csv` - you'd end up with `onfig_oe`.

You can either use `strings.TrimRight` (still a cutset but limited to the end of the string) or because you know the files end in `.csv`, just use `strings.Replace` again with ".csv" - in this case, `strings.Replace` will look for the exact string and not a cut set.

Comment: the strings package `TrimSuffix`/`CutSuffix` for this